Error: AnchorError caused by account: monster. Error Code: ConstraintSeeds. Error Number: 2006. Error Message: A seeds constraint was violated
As the title says, I encountered an error while running,hope everyone can help. Thank you very much everyone
test.ts
  it("spawn monster", async () => {
    const [gameAddress] = createGameAddress(); // core
    const [playerAddress] = createPlayerAddress(gameAddress);

    const playerAccount = await program.account.player.fetch(playerAddress);

    const monsterIndex = playerAccount.nextMonsterIndex.subn(1); // core

    const [monsterAddress] = createMonsterAddress(gameAddress, monsterIndex);

    const createMonsterSignature = await program.methods
      .spawnMonster()
      .accountsPartial({
        game: gameAddress,
        playerAccount: playerAddress,
        monster: monsterAddress,
        player: player.publicKey,
        systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
      })
      .rpc();

    await confirmTransaction(createMonsterSignature, provider);

    console.log("Create monster success");
  });


player.rs
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreatePlayer<'info> {
    pub game: Box<Account<'info, Game>>,
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [
            b"PLAYER",
            game.key().as_ref(),
            player.key().as_ref()
        ],
        bump,
        payer = player,
        space = ANCHOR_DISCRIMINATOR + Player::INIT_SPACE
    )]
    pub player_account: Account<'info, Player>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub player: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

PDA monster
const createMonsterAddress = (
  gameAddress: PublicKey,
  monsterIndex: anchor.BN
) =>
  findProgramAddress([
    Buffer.from(MONSTER_SEEDS),
    gameAddress.toBuffer(),
    monsterIndex.toArrayLike(Buffer, "le", MONSTER_INDEX_BYTE_LENGTH),
    player.publicKey.toBuffer(),
  ]);


instruction.rs
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct SpawnMonster<'info> {
    pub game: Box<Account<'info, Game>>,
    #[account(
        mut,
        has_one = game,
        has_one = player,
    )]
    pub player_account: Box<Account<'info, Player>>,
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [
            b"MONSTER",
            game.key().as_ref(),
            player.key().as_ref(),
            player_account.next_monster_index.to_le_bytes().as_ref()
        ],
        bump,
        payer = player,
        space = ANCHOR_DISCRIMINATOR + Monster::INIT_SPACE
    )]
    pub monster: Account<'info, Monster>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub player: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}


could you post the full error log and Player account.

@Jimii      Error: AnchorError caused by account: monster. Error Code: ConstraintSeeds. Error Number: 2006. Error Message: A seeds constraint was violated.
Program log: Left:
Program log: 8sbqza8zKTeLUdWHMtB9uagxT3dFQfPf53YJ56gCizXj
Program log: Right:
Program log: HsCgrJKsT2BeXAVcfkzCB1KMQxh3LjqppoGo92Y55NPz

@Jimii i updated

could you also post how you are deriving the moster account on the client side

i add more monster account, can you help me see

updated my answer

Even if I change the way the bytes are transferred or arrange them in the correct order, it still fails, I can't understand

i think the  problem is  monsterIndex , i have changed by remove subn and it worked

The error you are getting is because there is a mismatch between the address that anchor is deriving on the program side and the one you are deriving on you client.
Check on how you are deriving the monster account in the SpawnMonster instruction
const playerAcc = await program.account.playerAccount.fetch(playerAccAddr);

function findMonsterAddress(): anchor.web3.PublicKey {
  return anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [
      Buffer.from(MONSTER_SEEDS),
      gameAddress.toBuffer(),
      player.toBuffer(),
      new BN(playerAcc.nextMonsterIndex).toBuffer("le", 8);
    ],
    program.programId
  )[0];
}

